# Como salvar campos no banco de dados com letras maiúscula com Nodejs, TypeORM e Postgres?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Como posso salvar alguns campos de um objeto com letras maiúsculas? Eu sei converter strings com o ToUpperCase, mas no exemplo abaixo eu não sei como fazer. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
 const createProduct = productsRepository.create({
    follow_up,
    name,
    product,
    size,
    name_color,
    code_color,
    status,
    code_karsten,
    price,
    image,
    isActive,
});

await productsRepository.save(createProduct);

return createProduct;
```

No caso acima, preciso que apenas o campo product seja convertido em maiúsculo.

Comment: Como assim?......

Comment: oi @CmteCardeal, eu criei uma resposta para isso, talvez uma explicação do que o AP quer esteja nela.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) para a criação de objetos JavaScript. A maneira que utilizou é a que eu vou chamar de maneira abreviada (A notação de objeto literal), que foi introduzida no es5.

Desta forma, segue um exemplo:

```
 const name = 'nome';
 const product = 'produto';

 //notação maneira abreviada de criação de objetos
 const tudo = { name, product }

 //utilizando a notação literal...
 const tudo2 = {name, product: product.toUpperCase() };
 // Object { name: "nome", product: "PRODUTO" }
```

Para saber mais consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Para o seu caso específico a solução seria o seguinte:

```
const createProduct = productsRepository.create({
    follow_up,
    name,
    product: product.toUpperCase(),
    size,
    name_color,
    code_color,
    status,
    code_karsten,
    price,
    image,
    isActive,
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado... consegui de uma forma bem  parecida com a sua. Estou deixando ela aqui nos comentários para quem precisar. Na verdade eu precisa era no name e não do product como eu tinha postado anteriormente. Valeu...

Comment: @OrciolyAndradeAlves, entendi, mas na sua pergunta você diz: `preciso que apenas o campo product seja convertido em maiúsculo.`  Por isso eu fiz dessa forma, de qualquer forma, ficou claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

fiz da seguinte forma:

```
const nameToUpperCase = name.toString().toUpperCase();

const createProduct = productsRepository.create({
  follow_up,
  name: nameToUpperCase,
  product,
  size,
  name_color,
  code_color,
  status,
  code_karsten,
  price,
  image,
  isActive,
});

await productsRepository.save(createProduct);

return createProduct;
```

Obrigado a todos pela a dica!!!

Answer (score -3):

Assim também funciona:

```
const createProduct = productsRepository.create({
  follow_up,
  name: name.toUpperCase(),
  product,
  size,
  name_color,
  code_color,
  status,
  code_karsten,
  price,
  image,
  isActive,
});

await productsRepository.save(createProduct);

return createProduct;
```